# Cron Could not open input file when runs

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I don't know about `cron jobs` and I am trying to set them in my cPanel, so I have 2 php files I am trying to run:

```
covid-19_data.php
```

And `utilities.php`

on cPanel I run:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q -f /public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/data/shared/utilities.php
```

And

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/siteName/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/covid-19_data.php
```

But i keep receiving:

```
Could not open input file: /public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/data/shared/utilities.php
```

And

```
Warning: include_once(../shared/utilities.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/siteName/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/covid-19_data.php on line 3

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../shared/utilities.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php') in /home1/siteName/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/covid-19_data.php on line 3

Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in /home1/siteName/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/covid-19_data.php on line 12

Fatal error: Call to undefined function downloadFile() in /home1/siteName/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/covid-19_data.php on line 16
```

I tried running `utilities.php` every minute and `covid-19_data.php` every two minutes but doesn't work.

When I need to make it work, I only manually run via the browser wwww... `covid-19_data.php` and works fine, I don't need to run `utilities.php` I only made it run to try if that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your host runs cron jobs as `nobody`, or some other user that does not have access to the files in your account. Try changing the permissions of `covid-19_data.php` to allow "other" to read/execute it:

```
chmod o+rx /home/siteName/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteName/scripts/covid-19_data.php
```